# View content of memcached

Tags: monitoring, logging, memcached

Are there any tools to explore what is currently cached inside a memcached pool? Not some much graphs, but the actual key/values currently stored.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `stats items` - i.e.

```
echo "stats items" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?! This only gives out the server statistics, doesn't retrieve any keys.

Answer (score 25):

The correct answer would be `echo "stats cachedump SLABS_ID LIMIT" | nc HOSTNAME PORT`

eg. `echo "stats cachedump 15 4" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211`

This would give the output on the lines of:

```
ITEM cache_path-comments%2Fpage%2F2 [2211 b; 1337195558 s]
ITEM cache_path-comments%2Fpage%2F5 [2205 b; 1337195558 s]
ITEM cache_path-comments%2Fpage%2F6 [2179 b; 1337195558 s]
ITEM cache_path-comments [2164 b; 1337195558 s]
END
```

***Note:** This is an undocumented command that is not supported by the memcached team and can be removed in any version. For the complete reference, check out [Understanding Memcached stats cachedump command](http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/12/24/Understanding-Memcached-stats-cachedump-command).*

Comment: cachedump is limited to an undocumented amount of data, not greated than 1-2mb
so it's not reliable

Answer (score 17):

#### memcached-tool

In the recent version of `memcached` there is also **`memcached-tool`** perl script, e.g. usage:

```
memcached-tool localhost:11211 dump | less
```

which dumps all keys and values.

#### memdump

To dump a list of keys from a server, use `memcdump`/`memdump` tool, e.g.

```
memcdump --servers=localhost
```

To dump all objects:

```
memcdump --servers=localhost | xargs -L1 -I% sh -c 'echo "get %" | nc localhost 11211'
```

To dump all key values into separate files:

```
while read -r key; do [ -f "$key" ] || echo "get $key" | nc localhost 11211 > "$key.dump"; done < <(memcdump --server localhost)
```

#### memccat

To print a key value, you can use `memccat` command, e.g.

```
memccat CACHE-KEY
```

#### Bash

To dump all keys in Bash shell, try:

```
exec {memcache}<>/dev/tcp/localhost/11211; printf "stats items\nquit\n" >&${memcache}; cat <&${memcache}
```

#### netcat

Here is example to get value of single item using `netcat`:

```
echo "get 13456_-cache-some_object" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

#### Python

See: [How to export all keys and values from memcached with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5730276/55075)

Comment: This answer helped me find the _actual_ memcached tool : **memcdump**. See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14491419/720360

Comment: I first had to `apt install libmemcached-tools`, but then it still wasn't on my path, so `/usr/share/memcached/scripts/memcached-tool localhost:11211 dump`.  Ubuntu 18.

Comment: On Mac OS X you can install `memdump` with `brew install libmemcached`

Answer (score 7):

Try using `telnet` command, e.g.:

```
$ telnet 0 11211
stats
stats items
set key 1 23 8
get key
```

Answer (score 7):

Install `libmemcached-tools` and then you can use this command to get all the keys:

```
memcdump --server=127.0.0.1
```

To see the contents, you can ask for a specific key:

```
memcat --server=127.0.0.1 SOME_KEY
```

or you can loop over the list of keys in Bash:

```
for key in $(memcdump --server=127.0.0.1); do echo ------ $key ------; memcat --server=127.0.0.1 $key; done
```

Make sure to use 127.0.0.1 (if you are running the command on the same host) because `localhost` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

In basic memcached I do not think there is any way of querying for keys stored in the server. The only think you can get is statistics related to storage and stored items.

Some vendors that have developed memcached compliant solutions, e.g. [Gear6](http://www.gear6.com/memcached-resources/query), have however added functionality to allow querying.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in $(memcdump --server=127.0.0.1);
  do echo -n "KEY :  $key ------> VALUE : ";
  memccat --server=127.0.0.1 $key;
done
```